# Is the telemetry from the Apollo Lunar rovers available?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, mapping, historical-data, lunar-rover

Are there publicly-available datasets of the telemetry from the Apollo lunar rovers? Was rover telemetry even recorded during those missions?

If such datasets exist, I would love to retrieve the (timestamped) trajectories taken, velocity profiles, power consumption, rover tilt, etc. and plot them on top of an orbital map of the sites explored.

**Edit**: Why am I asking this question?

I'm interested in quantifying trends in the telemetry collected by those rovers (if any) during their traverses over several kilometers. First, this could highlight the degradation of specific rover subsystems. Second, I am really interested in seeing whether astronauts were more cautious at the beginning of their mission and got more "comfortable" (or efficient) with their rover driving behaviors towards the end of their expedition. This should be reflected in the rover telemetry, if it exists.

Comment: The rover did carry a color TV camera, a box of electronics for the TV, a box of radio electronics, and an S-band dish antenna.  S-band was used for spacecraft tracking throughout the mission, so it's plausible that some position data was taken.  However, there was no data link between the vehicle and the radio, so no power consumption, attitude, or tilt data.  This is from memory; I will write a proper answer later.

Comment: That's a great question! I'd love to know, too.

Comment: Thanks @DrSheldon! I however wonder whether if someone re-generated the exact trajectory taken by the rovers on high-resolution orbital maps, and the approximate time it took to navigate between waypoints.
My motivation is to find out whether astronauts were more cautious at the beginning of their mission and got more "comfortable" (or efficient) with their rover driving behaviors towards the end of the mission. That should have been reflected in the telemetry of the rovers. It would have also helped to identify degrading subsystems after kilometres of driving.

Comment: @OlivierLamarre it sounds like you really want to ask if there is any record of *tracking*, so asking if there is any *telemetry* is not exactly what you want to ask. There's a fancy term for this, see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/303080) All the information in your comment is really interesting very helpful to readers and those who may want to write an answer, so I recommend you move it back up into the question itself and adjust the title accordingly.

Comment: Once there are answers we shouldn't change the question substantially, but until then it's strongly encouraged to ensure that answers don't get posted that don't address what you are looking for. *Thanks!* Cool question btw :-)

Comment: Good point! I fell in the XY trap :)
Just edited my question with a clarification on why I asked this question.

Comment: Apollo technical reports sometimes contain transcribed telemetry. Unsure how useful these might be. [This document](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19740003321/downloads/19740003321.pdf) contains LRV traverse data and plots in the later pages. [And this document](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/lunar/documents/NTRS/collection2/NASA_TR_R_401.pdf) contains some lunar (Apollo 15) mobility performance data from pdf page 46 onwards.

Comment: Thanks @S.Low! I will look into these reports.

Comment: @OlivierLamarre Apologies for replying to this question again, but I recently watched [a talk that coincidentally discussed LRV data analysis](https://youtu.be/Ufxm9HAPStk?t=1130) and it reminded me of your project. Again unsure how useful it might be, but it is at least interesting.

Comment: Oh that's awesome! Thanks for getting back to me again